# RegExp numbers between single quotes

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a string like this `"f_details('277095');">`.   I just need to get the `277095` part.  I've been trying variations of `strPattern = "'[0-9]'+"`, but this is either finding nothing or finding the wrong things.

I don't understand regular expressions despite having a cheat sheet right in front of me.  Spent an hour trying different things already.  What would this regexp look like?

Here is my code that I use to scrape this site and grab data:

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

on error resume next
For i=1 To 77 '77 Counties

If i=77 Then Exit For

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://lic.ok.gov/PublicPortal/OREC/FindAssociateEntity.jsp"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop

Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 10: Loop
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("AddrCountyCode").Value = i

Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 10: Loop
For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If btn.name = "btnSearch" Then btn.Click()
NEXT

strPattern = "'(\d+)'"

strTestString = ie.document.body.innerhtml

arrAllMatches = fGetMatches(strPattern, strTestString)

If UBound(arrAllMatches) <> 0 Then 

filename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\License.txt"

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set ts = fso.opentextfile(filename,8,true) 
ts.write Join(arrAllMatches, vbCrlf)
ts.close 

Else

WScript.Echo "-- None Found --"

End if

next
Wscript.echo "DONE!"

'=====================================================================
Function fGetMatches(sPattern, sStr)
Dim regEx, retVal, sMatch, colMatches, temp
Set regEx = New RegExp     ' Create a regular expression.
regEx.Pattern = sPattern   ' Set pattern.
regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.
regEx.Global = True        ' Set global applicability.

Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(sStr)   ' Execute search.

If colMatches.Count = 0 Then
    temp = Array("")
Else
    '# Convert Collection to Array
    For Each sMatch In colMatches
        temp = temp & sMatch & "¶"
    Next
    temp = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1)
    temp = Split(temp, "¶")
End If

fGetMatches = temp
End Function
```

Comment: put the plus symbol next to the character class `"'[0-9]+'"`

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Tried strPattern = "'[0-9]+'", but no returns

Comment: @JNYRanger... Using in VBS, if that's what you mean.

Comment: VBS! Gross!  (VB-anything is my nemesis)

Comment: @JNYRanger...   haha...   I know I know...  At the moment, it's my comfort zone.  I also have a certain level of comfort with Python, so I'll probably abandon this ship soon.  For now, I just need to get this regexp to work and I'll be set.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'\d+'
```

Just add quantifier to `\d` instead of `'` as you want `\d` to repeat.

Try `(?<=')\d+(?=')` if you want to get only `277095`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/6

```
Dim strRegex as String = "'\d+'"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim strTargetString As String = "f_details('277095');"

For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
     If myMatch.Success Then
     ' Add your code here
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Hmm... Tried adding like this: strPattern = "\d'[0-9]\d'+", and this strPattern = "\d'[0-9]+".  No returns.

Comment: @Drivium you dont need `[0-9]`.just use `'\d+'` straightaway

Comment: (?<=')\d+(?=') & '\d+' don't seem to be working.  (?<=')\d+(?=') doesn't error, but also doesn't produce any results.   '\d+' errors.

Comment: I do see that it works at the link you provided, so I'm not sure why it's not working in my case.  Great site for testing by the way, never knew about that one.

Comment: I think just searching for the numbers between ' would do.

Comment: VBScript means it's the JavaScript flavor, so you can't use lookbehinds.  But @Drivium is right, lookaround is overkill for this job.

Comment: I misspoke, '\d' doesn't "error", it just finds nothing.

Comment: I modified OP to include the code I'm using this in.

Comment: @Drivium try `'[0-9]+'`

Comment: '([^']+)' seems to find EVERYTHING within single quotes - including the single quotes.  Trying to mod to include only numbers, but I'm just fumbling around.

Comment: @Drivium try `'\\d+'`

Comment: After fixing my underlying problem (my code wasn't allowing the tables to fully load, so it was grabbing the form html as opposed to the table which made this regex find nothing), this got me most of the way there.  This still produced the ' on both sides, but I modded to only produce a single ', which I used in a replace function to plug in the URL for each line.  I replaced "'" with this "https://lic.ok.gov/PublicPortal/OREC/FindAssociateEntity_Detail.jsp?lid=&FolderRSN="  Final URL: https://lic.ok.gov/PublicPortal/OREC/FindAssociateEntity_Detail.jsp?lid=&FolderRSN=428915.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

VBScript's regexp implementation is restricted, but if you follow the general rule "Keep it simple", even here you can cut a sequence of numbers easily:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> s = "f_details('277095');"
>> WScript.Echo r.Execute(s)(0).Value
>>
277095
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly to Vks answer, you can use capturing groups to capture the content you need.

You can use a regex like this:

```
'(\d+)'
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL6eF6/1)**

You can see highlighted in blue the match and in green the captured content

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [11-17] `277095`
```

Comment: Yea, I tried it anyway, but vks called it.  Not working.  I added my code above.  Might be easier to see it in action.

Comment: I ran my code and had resulting html print to a text file.  Looks like the innerhtml is the html of the form, not the resulting output.  I think this is why no patterns working.  Not sure how to point the html in the resulting table at the moment, but researching.